# For which $n \ge 2$ is $2^{1/n}$ a sum of roots of unity?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Find all integers $n\ge 2$ such that $2^{1/n}$ is a sum of roots of unity.
>
> *Source:* [Problem $2.18$](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Evywang/VW-20180615-KB-algconjNT.pdf)

It seems the problem refers to finite sums (infinite sums will not converge absolutely in this case) and no repetition of the said roots of unity. However, it's not clear if we're allowed to use roots of unity from $$S_m : =\{x \in \mathbb C: x^m = 1\}$$
for a fixed $m\in \mathbb N$, or if there's more flexibility, i.e., if we can choose roots of unity from $S := \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty S_m$.

The first case seems simpler to handle, though I am equally interested in the second case also. In the first case, suppose $n\ge 2$ is an integer such that $2^{1/n}$ is a sum of $m$th roots of unity, i.e., $2^{1/n} = \alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha _k$ for some $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k \in S_m$ and $\alpha_i \ne \alpha_j$ for every $i \ne j$. Then, $2 = (\alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha _k)^n$. The triangle inequality doesn't say anything useful, since it yields the bound $2 = |\alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha _k|^n \le k^n$. How should I proceed? Thanks for any hints or ideas.

Comment: Using $m$th roots of unity for a fixed $m$ is equivalent to using arbitrary roots of unity because $S_{m_1} \cup S_{m_2} \cup \cdots \cup S_{m_k} \subseteq S_{m_1 m_2 \cdots m_k}$

Comment: That's a nice observation, thanks! @Dylan

Comment: Infinite sums won't converge at all, not just absolutely.